# map c++ with const char* keys retrieves null

Tags: c++, dictionary

So, I am trying to learn `map` in C++. I put the type as `std:: map <const char *, int>` to a variable `month`.

Say, the data is `month["Jul"] = 7;`

When I tried to retrieve the value directly

```
printf("%d", month["Jul"]);
```

It succeeds and outputs the value.

```
7
```

Trying with another variable succeeds too.

```
const char *p = "Jul";
printf("%d", month[p]); // 7
```

But strange behavior happens when I tried to assign it with a given input.

```
const char in_month[3];
scanf("%s", in_month);
print("%d". month[in_month]);
```

It retrieves `(null)`

```
0
```

Did I do something forbidden here or was there a step that I missed?

Comment: Have you tried using C++ idioms instead of C idioms?

Comment: @Eljay if you refer to ```std:: cin``` or ```std:: cout```, I've done and it results in the same.

Comment: `std::string`, `std::cin`, `std::cout`, not using `printf`, not using `const char*`, not using `scanf`.  A [mcve] would be useful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `const char*` as the key, `std::map` will compare on the pointer directly, but not the content pointed by the pointer. For [c-style string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes), the identical string literals might be compared as equal, but this is not guaranteed.

> The compiler is allowed, but not required, to combine storage for equal or overlapping string literals. That means that identical string literals may or may not compare equal when compared by pointer.

When you use the array `in_month`, after converting to pointer it points to different things, then the pointer comparison result is `false`.

Better to use `std::string` instead as `std:: map <std::string, int>`. `std::string` has well-defined [comparison operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) which compares based on the content of string.

Comment: I agree with you. I encounter some strange outputs with the given input chars. I would go with your advice using ```std:: string``` before my codes turn into spaghetti.

Comment: @NabilAsykar The strange outputs? It might come from the declaration of the array `in_month`, which contains 3 elements and can't stroe string literal `"Jul"`, which has 4 `char`s including the null terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: yup doesn't work I setup a test online it fails. https://onlinegdb.com/r1tcJ_xaU